# Is there a way to iterate over a list of couple in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

I would like to draw a list of 2D points with tikz and additionally draw these points multiplied by a certain factor alpha.

If the y-coordinate was a function of the x-coordinate, it would be easy to do it automatically as follow (alpha = 3 and y = x^2).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach[count=\i] \x in {-1,0.2,0.7,1}{
            \filldraw (\x,\x^2) circle (.6pt) node[below left] {$a_{\i}$};
            \filldraw (3*\x,3*\x^2) circle (.6pt) node[below left] {$b_{\i}$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to automate the drawing similarly when y is not a function of x.

It would be easy if we could iterate over a list of couples (with a syntax like `for \x,\y in {(0.1,0.2),(0.4,0.8),(0.9,3)}`) but I don't think it is possible.
Another way to automate the drawing would be to use lists of two elements (in the programming sense) but I have found no information on the existence of lists (the programming structure, not what you would obtain with \itemize) in latex.

Comment: `for \x/\y in {0.1/0.2,0.4/0.8,0.9/3}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slashes instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x/\y in {0/1, 0.5/3, 2.2/6}{
            \filldraw (\x, \y) circle (.6pt) node[below left] {$a_{0}$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]